# Is honey toxic when heated up in tea?

Tags: medical-science, toxicology, honey, tea

Last night, we ran out of sugar so I suggested to add honey in tea but my cousin said it would have very harmful effect on health and then he showed me these [link1](https://markbunn.com.au/blog/honey-never-put-it-in-hot-water-teas), [link2](http://www.thehealthyhomeeconomist.com/is-cooking-honey-unhealthy/) claiming:

> While warm water is fine, according to Maharishi Ayurveda, above 42 degrees centigrade, the all-important ‘medicinal’ molecular structure of honey is changed irrevocably, making it indigestible (in a sense…toxic!!!).

Is it  true?

Comment: For reference, here's an article from some Ayurveda site that makes more specific claims: http://www.ayurvedicyogi.com/honey-ayurvedic-nectar-or-poisin/

Comment: And here's a study on heating honey, no time to make an answer right now: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3215355/

Comment: Unfortunately the study is talking a lot about heating honey to 60° and 140°, whereas the original article talks about 42° as the limit.

Comment: Even if somethnig is indigestible, it doesn't mean that it's toxic. One example for this are [dietary fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietary_fiber).

Comment: It's worth stressing that Maharishi Ayurveda is a controversial system of alternative medicine (not, as I first thought, the person making the claim), and the definitions of "medicinal" and "toxic" here are likely to be very different from those used by mainstream science. This may make the entire claim hard to analyse without investigating the evidence for the entire belief system.

Comment: Quite right, to answer this QA would essentially be answering the question: "It is generally agreed by scientists that 'ayurveda' is nonsense; is there anything to this specific claim about honey that isn't nonsensical?"

Comment: This could be quite simply answered by looking for e.g. ER admissions and/or death certificates listing the cause of death as "drinking warm honey".

Comment: @jamesqf -- Or ER admissions listing cause of death as "eating bread cooked with honey instead of sugar". Or lots of other foods cooked with honey instead of sugar. Or spreading honey on hot toast which definitely gets over 42 °C (108 °F). Or spreading pasteurized honey on cold bread, as commercial honey is pasteurized by briefly heating to over 70 °C (160 °F).

Comment: The claim is that heated honey is indigestible, not toxic. A meta claim is that indigestible items are inherently toxic.

Comment: @fredsbend: Both the title and the body of the question say "toxic".

Comment: @James It says the "molecular structure of honey is changed irrevocably, making it indigestible (in a sense…toxic!!!)." The claim is "indigestible". Toxic is in parentheses, further clarified as not being used in the typical sense either ("in a sense").

Comment: @fredsbend: Yes, that's what it says, 'toxic'.  That the quoted text equates indigestability with toxicity is only additional evidence of their ignorance :-)

Comment: @Matt The toxicity of sugar is charged topic. I've been thinking about making an answer, but I don't know how it wouldn't eventually become an answer on the toxicity of sugar. HMF is mentioned at length in the second link, and I suspect that's what is being accused as toxic. It's hard to answer a claim that is using terms incorrectly.

Comment: @fredsbend I guess the point of my comment is that if honey has a problem then sugar does too. So any claim that honey is bad and sugar isn't has got to be bollocks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this could be answered by anything other then "This ayurveda stuff is known gibberish and their definitions of "toxic" don't align with the dictionary definition".

Comment: @matt_black That's only true if the "1% other stuff" is inert. It doesn't take much "contaminant" to make something toxic; or, for that matter, much "mineral content" to make it beneficial. It would be perfectly possible for natural honey to be toxic in a way that refined sugar is not.

Comment: @IMSoP Plenty of things are possible in principle but entirely unknown in practice. I'd be gobsmacked to see any example of a compound with "medicinal properties" when cool that is toxic when warmed in hot tea (which is what is claimed). Extraordinary claims demand extraordinary evidence.

Comment: @matt_black Right, but that's *a completely different criticism* from saying "honey is chemically identical to (refined) sugar". I could pick holes in that argument, as well, but I won't, because *this isn't a site for discussing theoretical science*. As I said under DevSolar's answer, if somebody could find a study listing the nutritional composition of honey before and after heating, we could at least have a basis against which to judge the claim.

Comment: @IMSoP It isn't a *completely* different criticism from a chemist's point of view as impure (not refined) sugar is a pretty good description of what honey is. The impurities are in trace amounts which for most purposes would be ignored unless proven to be important. Which they haven't been.

Comment: @Matt The deletion of the answer with the German source and the persistence of MaxW's answer is exactly why I didn't want to make my own answer. This community has a very strange way of applying their rules.

Comment: @fredsbend I can't be sure (without enough rep to view deleted posts), but I think DevSolar deleted their own answer, possibly in response to a perception that I was criticising it. Note that it had 11 upvotes and no downvotes when I last saw it, so "the community" was not reacting particularly badly to it. For the record, I did not think it was a terrible answer either, just that it could be a lot better if a better source was found for what actually happens when you heat honey, rather than relying on marketing and common sense.

Comment: @IMSoP Let's hope so. I would be sorely disappointed in the moderators if they deleted that answer, but not the other.

Comment: That would be the content that is not water or sugar. Honey contains an antimicrobial peptide called bee defensin-1. Some studies show that honey can kill methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus (MRSA), β-haemolytic streptococci and vancomycin-resistant Enterococci. If this is destroyed by heat the honey would just be sugar and water.

Comment: "Sola dosis facit venenum." Even water can be toxic: about 6 liters if ingested and even less than 2 liters when inhaled.

Comment: If heating honey in *tea* (which can never get above about 212º F) makes it "toxic", then millions of people for thousands of years should have been being poisoned by it in their *baking* (where temps routinely go above 300º F)

Answer (score 32):

Let me start off with my conclusion as a chemist...

I absolutely don't believe that heating honey in hot water would make the liquid  indigestible or toxic.

**The claim**

1. The webpages cited by the OP, and many others, claim that heating honey in water makes it "unsafe" (I'm lumping indigestible and toxic into one category).

   > Without any reference to some other more authoritative source it is impossible to track the assertions back to a reputable source. So the story becomes based on reference to a vague and unknown authority.
2. The OP states: *While warm water is fine, according to Maharishi Ayurveda, above 42 degrees centigrade, the all-important ‘medicinal’ molecular structure of honey is changed irrevocably, making it indigestible (in a sense…toxic!!!).*

   > User IMSoP points out that [Maharishi Ayurveda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharishi_Vedic_Approach_to_Health) is a controversial system of alternative medicine, and the definitions of "medicinal" and "toxic" here are likely to be very different from those used by mainstream science.

**General Scientific background**

1. "Detecting" harmful substances

   > Analytical chemistry has progressed to the point where trace and ulta-trace levels of substances can be detected. For instance it may come as a shock but all the food that you have eaten has been radioactive, and scientists can easily detect that radioactivity. For example in the upper atmosphere nitrogen is converted to a radioactive isotope of hydrogen known as [tritium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritium#Cosmic_rays) and a radioactive isotope of carbon known as [carbon-14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-14#Natural_production_in_the_atmosphere). [Cyanide](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/toxprofiles/tp8-c1.pdf) can also be detected in some foods and naturally in the human body. So just because some "toxic chemical" can be detected doesn't make the food itself toxic. So ALL foods have some sort of toxic component and we obviously can't stop eating any food.
2. 5% Detection level for a problem in a study.

   > Let's say that a rat study has found a 5% chance of a problem of some sort -- total body weight, liver weight, lung weight, tail length, rickets, whatever. That is basically like flipping a coin and get 4 heads in a row. Not very likely if you only do one trial of four tosses, but if you do 50 trials (i.e. test for 50 different things) then you are bound to detect some "abnormalities."
3. Null result in an animal study

   > The worse result for an animal study is to find no problems at all. Thus all  the money (time and effort) spend to do the animal study yielded nothing. Rather think of an animal study as a stress test. The animal testing hopefully uses doses of the chemical which hopefully will cause some problems but not just instantly kill the animal. So out of the thousand ways that the chemical might harm the animal the study will hopefully find the first half-dozen that are the most sensitive to the chemical (i.e. the canary in the coal mine warning). Additional testing can then focus on those metabolic systems or organs. For instance is it the chemical itself that causes the problem or is it some metabolic product of the chemical that causes the problem?
4. Impossible to prove a chemical is safe

   > It is impossible to prove that a chemical is safe. The chemical could always be harmful at a level too low for the particular study to detect. So does 1 person in a 100 get cancer or 1 in a 1,000 or 1 in 10,000 and so on. Obviously you don't to use any chemical that causes cancers, but no rat study has ever been done with a million rats. So rather than using a million rats, a few rats are given doses of the chemical high enough to stress the rats used. So it is possible only to test to show that a chemical is unsafe at a particular level.
5. Number of chemicals tested

   > The appalling truth is that only a [tiny fraction](http://sage-bcgc.berkeley.edu/chemical-screening) of the chemicals that chemists have identified have been adequately safety tested.
6. Chemical X

   > If 100 trace chemicals in honey were tested and not shown to be problematic critics can always point to the mysterious Chemical X which hasn't yet been detected as the culprit. With millions of chemicals identified there is always another one.

**Scientific Background of Problem**

1. [Honey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey#Nutritional_and_sugar_profile) is about 73% of various sugars and about 17% water according to Wikipedia.
2. [5-(Hydroxymethyl)furfural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxymethylfurfural) (HMF) is a chemical that is derived from dehydration of certain sugars. Basically it is formed as one of the chemicals formed early in the caramelization process.
3. HMF forms due to Time or temperature

   > HMF isn't found in "new" honey just deposited by bees, but it is formed in honey that has been heated. HMF will also form as a function of time. The general rule of thumb in chemistry that every 10 C (18 F) increase in temperature doubles the reaction rate.
4. When honey is diluted with water then the reaction rate to form HMF would slow down. So HMF forms fastest in concentrated sugar solutions.
5. It is recommended, [Mayo Clinic for example](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/infant-and-toddler-health/expert-answers/infant-botulism/faq-20058477), that babies less than one year old not be given any honey because of the risk of C. botulinum spores. After a year the human stomach contains enough acid to kill the spores.

   > Honey is not process at pressuring canning temperatures 115 C (240 F) which would kill the spores because that would significantly caramelize the honey. Think of the "off-taste" of canned milk as compared to fresh milk.

**Scientific Evidence for the claim**

1. Annapoorani A, Anilakumar KR, Khanum F, Murthy NA, Bawa AS. Studies on the physicochemical characteristics of heated honey, honey mixed with ghee and their food consumption pattern by rats. Ayu. 2010;31(2):141-146. doi:10.4103/0974-8520.72363.

   > The Journal is *The International Quarterly Journal of Research in Ayurveda*.
   >
   > > *I have no idea how prestigious this journal is, but I have my doubts.*
   >
   > They did find 5-(Hydroxymethyl)furfural (HMF) but that chemical is found in numerous other food products including baked goods (really high in toasted bread) and roasted coffee beans ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxymethylfurfural#Occurrence_in_food)).
   >
   > Their data did not find any harmful effects. (i.e. statistically significant differences)
   >
   > Only the last sentence of the article throws in the statement "The study revealed that heated honey (>140°C) mixed with ghee produces HMF which *may produce deleterious effects and act as a poison in due course.*" [emphasis mine]
   >
   > > *Thus it seems that the assertion of being "harmful" is suddenly made to support the teachings of Ayurveda rather than based on scientific evidence.*
   > >
   > > The conclusion of the study also notes that "The study has shown that heating of honey reduces the specific gravity with a subsequent raise in ash value..." The rise in ash value makes no sense chemically. To ash a sample you heat it to a red hot heat to burn off any organic material. Ash is mineral reside. The key point here is not really to challenge the study but to point out that if you test for 50 things at a 5% confidence level then you're bound to get some false positive results.
2. There is evidence that bees are killed by HMF. For instance a study by [Zirbes et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24127696) and [Krainer et al](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26590927). Also a study of high-fructose corn syrup (HFCS) as a sucrose replacement for honey bees by [LeBlanc et al](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19645504).

   > I didn't go to far down this rabbit hole. Note though that 500 mg/kg and 500 ppm (parts per million) are 0.05% of the food weight. Also note the bee larva were only fed with HMF containing food.
3. There was at least one rat study that found HMF harmful.

**Scientific Evidence against the claim**

1. Magic temperature of 42 Celsius claimed by Ayurveda.

   > There is absolutely nothing magic about the temperature of 42 C. Yes water freezes at 0 C and boils at 100 C. But there is a valid chemical reason why those numbers are special. Any reaction in honey that takes place at 42 C will take place at 41 C only the reaction will be about 7% slower. So a magic temperature of 42 C is nonsense chemically.
2. There is no scientific study which shows that HMF is harmful to humans as supported by a 2011 study by [Abraham et al](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21462333).
3. A Section of the Wikipedia named ["As an Unwanted Component"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxymethylfurfural#As_an_unwanted_component) (with scientific references) notes that HMF is found in numerous foods. The point is that detection in honey isn't that unusual chemically.
4. HMF has been considered as a [drug to treat sickle cells](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v515/n7526_supp/full/515S4a.html) in humans.
5. Honey has been analyzed for HMF to indicate "quality" of honey, but not that HMF makes honey toxic.

   > Chemical reactions happen slowly at low temperatures and more quickly at high temperatures. So high HMF levels could indicate that the honey has been stored too long (3 years say), or that it has been stored at too high a temperature (140 F warehouse).
   >
   > HMF was also used to check for adulterated honey. Thus honey extended with sugar syrup could be detected.

**Anecdotal Evidence against the claim**

1. There is no scientific study that I could find which claims that heating honey in water makes the liquid toxic to humans. The temperature and time profile won't create "significant" levels of HMF.
2. People have been adding honey to tea for centuries. If tea drinkers had noticed a problem it would seem that some scientist would have studied the tea/honey problem. Why are there no such tea/honey studies?
3. The [recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/9454/baklava/) for making baklava includes a step where you add sugar and honey to water and boil it. You then soak the baked pastry in the liquid. Baklava eaters aren't complaining either.
4. [Beemaid](http://www.beemaid.com/pasteurization-of-honey) honey is pasteurized to 160 F (71 C) to kill yeast which might ferment the honey.

   > What company would want its honey to ferment on the shelf? So I strongly suspect this is more common than most grocery store bands want to admit. For instance [Barkman](http://www.barkmanhoney.com/honey/faqs/) (Buzy Bee Brand) only admits that their honey is "gently warmed."
5. There are numerous recipes in which honey is baked.

   > For examples: A [Honey Bun](http://www.barkmanhoney.com/recipe/honey-buns/), [Honey Wheat Rolls](http://www.barkmanhoney.com/recipe/honey-wheat-rolls/), [Honey Candied Bacon](http://www.barkmanhoney.com/recipe/honey-candied-bacon/), [Honey Puff Pancakes](http://www.barkmanhoney.com/recipe/honey-puff-pancakes/) and [Mexican Honey Flan](http://www.barkmanhoney.com/recipe/mexican-honey-flan/).
6. In winter my store bought honey will sometimes crystallize. I microwave it to warm it up. I am still alive writing this ...

**Conclusion**

I certainly would not advocate changing your diet to include 10% HMF. But at low  levels (really trace levels...) it has not been shown to be harmful.

*Please note that if you do believe that trace amounts of HMF are harmful then adjust your WHOLE diet accordingly. This means that any food product with natural or added sugars which has been heated should be excluded. So no coffee (the beans have sugar and are roasted), no baked goods, no jellies, no maple syrup, no commercial applesauce, etc etc etc.*

As a chemist I'm amazed how the general public thinks all "chemicals," or any "chemical treatment" is toxic. All the food we eat is chemical in nature. Don't let the mention of the word *chemical* give you the hives [bee pun intended ;-) ]. To a chemist a strawberry is not "a" chemical but a bag full of thousands of chemicals.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53682/discussion-on-answer-by-maxw-is-honey-toxic-when-heated-up-in-tea).

Comment: I think it is a little unfair to flag this as *theoretical*. It does a pretty good job of summarising a rage of relevant facts and background.

Comment: @matt_black the banner was put on on a very different version ;-)

Comment: @Sklivvz Ah, living proof the banners promote the right behaviour to improve answers!

Comment: re: Magic temperature of 42 Celsius. What I have heard before is that you should not heat honey higher than 42° because then it looses it's 'healthiness'. To break that down, afaik, the claim comes from the fact that 1) Honey contains antibacterial proteins (http://www.fasebj.org/content/24/7/2576.short) 2) proteins degrade at high temperature and 3) 42°C is the highest fevers you can get - which are very dangerous. The logic is: high fever dangerous bc, it degenerates proteins. No proteins no antibacterial effect. Then some confusion between not good = bad / toxic. flawed - I know.